# Clear text on bluring TextBlock?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, opacity, textblock

I have this xaml code of my metro app.

```
    <Grid Width="531" Height="531">
        <Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding image1}" Stretch="UniformToFill"  />
        </Grid.Background>
        <StackPanel Background="#0072B0" Opacity="0.7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="White">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Opacity="1"  Style="{StaticResource BigTopDealItemTitle}"/>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

I wanna make a blur panel and clear text on it. But look like the text in TextBlock blur too, even I set Opacity of it with 1.

Comment: Is this wpf or metro?  It can't be both.

Comment: it is metro. I was wrote it at title :D

Comment: But you put wpf in the tags.  Wpf is not compatible with metro.  I fixed it.

Comment: owh, my apologize XD 
I'm newbie here

Comment: No problem, just trying to make sure your question is tagged correctly.

Comment: It's not a Stack Overflow tagging issue. It's a Metro vs WPF issue. They just aren't the same thing, whether you're asking on Stack Overflow or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a background blurry without making the textbox blurry do something like this:

```
<Grid Width="531" Height="531">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding image1}" Stretch="UniformToFill"  />
    </Grid.Background>
    <StackPanel Background="#0072B0" Opacity="0.7" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="White"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Style="{StaticResource BigTopDealItemTitle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This will put the `TextBlock` on top of the background (i.e. the `Border`) without it being affected by the properties of the `Border`.